# Using Python with a flexible remote library that resides in a different git repo?

Tags: python, shared, import

I work on a project that uses a lot of different git repos. Some are open source and some are closed source. Often times there is python code written that would be useful for both open and closed source sides of the project but it is not easy to share between the two.

I am wondering if anyone has a slick general way to solve this problem with out the obvious answer of "install your library on every system you want to run the scripts on" There are a few reasons why that is not a viable answer for us.

We have kicked around a few ideas. The simplest would be to have an open source library repo that we require people to sync before running scripts in either repo that utilizes it. While this works it is quite manual and could lead to issues like people having out of date versions or forgetting to sync the library themselves.

The other way I could see doing something like this would be to distribute a dummy python file that handles all the syncing and captures imports as they happen.

For example if I ran:
import favorite_lib

It would import the dummy favorite_lib.py I have in each repo that needs access to favorite lib that would then in turn git clone or git fetch the favorite_lib repo in the directory where the script lives.

With that in mind I would also like to do something like:

from favorite_lib import commands

favorite_lib would be sync'd and the commands.py file from the directory would be imported.

I haven't tried implementing the above but I believe it is mostly possible.

Am I missing some precedence for this use case? Does anyone else have a better idea? I have searched around and asked a number of people with no real concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)

Comment: This is definitely an interesting idea. It still isn't quite as automatic as I would like, people running scripts would have to be aware of the mechanics of submodules and need to update the libraries accordingly. I could make wrapper scripts that handle that in the actual submodule itself though. Still wondering if there is something more automatic out there. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, those are valid points. However, submodules also guarantee which revision of the submodule is being used. That way you can guarantee consistency across many teams and team members.